# jQuery drag and drop, duplicates clone on drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Not sure what is wrong, but when I drop item in second list, I'm editing that clone, html code on drop, and content that I'm adding to item, is being duplicated.

For example, I'm dropping an image, but on drop I want to add text box and label, my code is adding text box and label, but twice.

Here is my code :

```
$("#left-pane li").draggable({
    containment: '#gbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    connectToSortable: '#right-pane',
    appendTo: '#right-pane',
    start: function () {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
}).mousedown(function () {});

$("#right-pane").sortable({
    sort: function () {},
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    receive: function () {},
    update: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("#right-pane li").live('dblclick', function () {
    $(this).remove();
})

$("#right-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#left-pane li",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).append("<div class='single-item'><input type='text' class='item-title' /><br /><textarea class='item-text'></textarea></div>");
    }
});

$("#left-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#right-pane li",
    drop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="left-pane">
   <li><img src="example.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="example2.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="example3.png" /></li>
</ul>

<ul id="right-pane">
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide your html? Or providing a jsfiddle link would be nice too!

Comment: @Robodude it is added, I mean, html.

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1547)?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use  `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why it's adding it twice but here is a quick solution to fixing your problem. (It could be related to the bug that Iswanto San posted in the comments to the question).

http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/Y7RmR/

I updated your drop function to check and see if it already contains the div you're trying to add. If it does, then it won't place it a second time.

```
$("#right-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#left-pane li",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).children('.single-item').length == 0)
        {
            $(ui.draggable).append("<div class='single-item'><input type='text' class='item-title' /><br /><textarea class='item-text'></textarea></div>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hey thank you, that worked, I had just to check for length. Thank you.

Comment: on the right pane, how to place the dropped image on the dropped locations instead of placing image after image?